# std::unique_ptr conversion constructor from std::auto_ptr

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2013

According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) the following code should compile and work. It should construct a `unique_ptr` where the stored pointer is initialized with `ap.release()` and the stored deleter is value-initialized.

```
#include <memory>
int main()
{
   std::auto_ptr<int> ap(new int());
   std::unique_ptr<int> up(std::move(ap));
}
```

When I compile it (using VS2013 with the VS2010 toolset) I get the following error:

```
test.cpp(5): error C2664: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr(std::nullptr_t)' :
   cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::auto_ptr<_Ty>' to 'std::nullptr_t'
   with
   [
      _Ty=int
   ]
   nullptr can only be converted to pointer or handle types
```

Is this a bug in the compiler for the VS2010 toolset?

Comment: [Works fine with GCC.](http://ideone.com/LWj8P9)

Comment: Seems to be a bug. I get the same error as you in VC 2010 but it works fine with VC 2012.

Comment: @ComicSansMS: If your comment was an answer I would accept it as the accepted answer to this question.

Comment: @dalle There you go :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a bug.

I get the same error as you in VC 2010 but it works fine with VC 2012.

I'm not too good at tracking standard changes, but it seems this functionality was only added to the standard with [N3073](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3073.html) (see change `10.` on that page) which postdates the release of VC 2010.